# SwiftUI Text.DateStyle Timer change format

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am trying to create a Widget with SwiftUI, and I want to use the ".timer" style from Text to show a countdown, but the result of the `Text(entry.date, style: .timer)` is `1.34.23`.

I want to use `:` instead of `.` as separator.

And is it possible to add a leading zero so instead of this `1.34.23`, I want this `01:34:23`

Comment: I use a timer style in a widget and could not find a way to add a leading zero. I do see colons as a separator. I think the separator depends on your locale and what is the standard format to use in that country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the automatic environment locale as follows e.g.

```
Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(60), style: .timer)
    .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "en_GB"))

60:00
```

```
Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(60), style: .timer)
    .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "fi_FI"))

60.00
```

See here for how countries format times:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country

See here for iOS locale identifiers:

https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273